# Cannot use style with tailwind hooked

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code, react-hooks, tailwind-css

I'm new to react native and I'm trying to use tailwind just with basic configuration.
And not matter what I do , the style is not changing.

The code :

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {useTailwind} from 'tailwind-rn';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={useTailwind.style=("flex-1 justify-center items-center")}>
      <Text>This is test</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

And what I getting in the iPhone simulation :
[image]

Any idea why I cannot adding any style ?

Thanks !

Comment: simple, because you treated the hook function like an object.

Answer (score 0):

I just recharge the code and install other library :

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import tw from "tailwind-react-native-classnames";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={tw`flex-1 justify-center items-center`}>
      <Text >This is asd test</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```